# AsyncTask - update progress while ONE long operation completes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm working on an android app that has a lengthy process that I'd like to report the progress on.

I *don't* have the source to the process, so I can't get the process itself to report on it's percent complete. I have to wrap it somehow. I also need the process to run in the background.

To me, this seemed like a good case for an AsyncTask, but since I have *one* lengthy process, I can only report progress at the start, and end of the task.

**What's the best way in Android to write this, so I can report progress back to the UI while the lengthy process (for which I have no source) is running?**

I tried using an AsyncTask with a Handler in it, but that didn't seem to work (failed with: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()")

**EDIT:** Note, I'm calling "publishProgress" at the start and end of my long process. I need to figure out how to call it while my one huge process is running.

**EDIT 2:** The UI kills my process if I don't report back, so I have to report back while it's running...

Comment: Why can you just start and indefinate progress dialog (or whatever other kind of message you want to deliver) and then close/hide that onPostExecute? You don't need access to the process just access to the main thread right beofore it starts and after in onPostExecute

Comment: And it's a huge process that you don't own or control, right ? So as hacky as it is, why not spin off a thread in the asynch to do the publish progress (to keep your watchdog happy). What it publishes is up to you, but it'll need to wait for the spun off thread to finish via whichever primitive you want.

Comment: hmmm.... sounds reasonable.... i'll try it and see how it goes.... thanks!

Comment: Relax. There is no way to do it without changing the task's code.

Comment: @K5User: that worked! I didn't even need to use an AsyncTask.. thanks for the suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution as hackish as it gets.

```
public class LongAction {
    public AtomicBoolean finished = new AtomicBoolean();
    private final Handler h;      

    /* attributes you need */

    public LongAction(Handler h /* parameters you need to initialice attibutes */) {
        this.h = h;
        // Initialization
    }

    public void doLongTask() {
        finished.set(false);
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your long task
                finished.set(true);
            }
        }.run();
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!finished.get()) {
                }
                Message m = Message.obtain();
                m.what = 0;
                m.arg1 = 50;
                h.sendMessage(m);
            }
        }.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: from my tests, it seems like onProgressUpdate will only get called when I call [publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...)), which I'm doing at the start, and end of my lengthy process. I need some way to do it *while* the process is running... and I don't have the source to that process (3rd party lib) Thanks though!

Comment: After your edits I can only say you can't wrap that without access to the code. If it's a long operation I guess it's either a download or a file load, and only the code knows where it's at.

Comment: no idea if it's async or not... and for what it's worth, I don't really care about accurate progress.... i just want to be able to ping another service to let it know the task is still alive.... It's getting killed if I take too long without saying "still alive"....

Comment: Cleaned up and tested, as a class it should work. Doing it in-method is a bit messier because the finished variable may get cleaned up by GC.

Comment: It's not thread-safe: `finished` should be an `AtomicBoolean`.  It might have worked when you tested it, but there is no guarantee it will work all the time and on all devices.  Correctly testing multi-threaded code is nearly impossible.

Comment: Someone please edit the necessary changes, I'm not versed in atomic operations in Android.

Comment: Synchronized get and set should fix it too. Androidannotations provides a recipe for this.

Comment: I edited to AtomicBoolean.  However, that is still not quite the right to go about this because of the busy waiting loop.  It would be simpler and better to rewrite this with a [CountDownLatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do anything else since you don't have control over the long running task.  The basic AsyncTask looks enough for what you want.

You can display text that tells the user the operation is on-going (or start some animation) in AsyncTask.doInBackground().  And you then display the completion message (or stop the animation) in AsyncTask.onPostExecute().

I don't quite see what else you can do.  I don't think AsyncTask.onProgress() is useful for your case.

Not directly related: You might also want to disable some functionality in the Activity when the operation is on-going.  You also must be careful on what you want to do about the lifecycle (if the Activity is killed while the process is on-going).

Comment: thanks for the feedback.... my process is one of many processes similar processes that are managed by a manager. I need to fire my callback for "progress" or the manager process kills my process because it thinks it's dead ;-) So I can't really go changing what it does without changing lots of other code....

Comment: I don't get it.  In the OP, you only talked about updating the progress on the UI.  But you have to send updates to some manager too to avoid (something?) dying?

Comment: it's the same thing... The UI kills my task if it doesn't hear back from it... it's the manager.... and the UI has a manager that watches these child tasks and kills them if it doesn't hear back from them....

Comment: I still don't understand.  Something smells fishy.  Either you are not using this external library correctly, or it is a very badly designed library.  If it is the latter, you should really consider switching to some alternative solution, even if it is painful.  If it is this badly designed, there are probably other bugs and problems with this library and it will just give you more pain in the future, as well as making your own design messed up.

Comment: hey! i agree it's not a best case scenario, but I don't need to find a perfect solution, just one that works. And the library needs to stay as is. I tried using a timer instead of a handler, and it worked fine for my case... I didn't need to use AsyncTask after all for this, as my process was already in a thread. But I think the question itself still stands, as others may be in this situation some time as well. Thanks!